# Delphi DotMatrix Report Printing via Fast Report with same fr3 file but result with different font

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

sorry for my bad english, and sorry if my question not following the rules because this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I'm rewriting my internal office application which developed using Delphi but I dont have previous source code. For application reporting, i'm using the same FastReport .fr3 file from previous developer. But when i tried to print it out, it print out with different font. The Fast Report Preview before printing already same, but different after printed. Am i missed some settings?

here's the preview of the printed report:

my application report:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42816630/stackoverflow/my%20app%20report%20result.jpg

previous application report:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42816630/stackoverflow/previous%20app%20report%20result.jpg

The report using DotMatrix layout. I have drop TfrxDotMatrixExport. And also have tried to change font and layout for the print but still cannot achieve the same result.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question is under discussion in [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286525/strange-comment-cannot-contain-that-content-error)

Comment: May we assume that both those printouts are both from the exact same printer and that the old software still print out correctly in Dot Matrix format on that same printer?

Comment: Ow, I'm using Delphi XE2 with FastReport version 5.1.9. I'm sure the previous application developed using older version of Delphi and FastReport.

Yes I'm print the report to the same printer "Epson LQ-2180". The preview before print at in-application FastReport preview, show no different except for the values.

Comment: You'd perhaps be better off asking this question at the FR support forums, where you can actually upload the file in question and they can examine it. I'd link to it, but as you can see from the meta link I provided above I'm unable to do so. You can see the URL in the image I posted there, though. :-)  There's no indication here that the problem is not specific to your situation, and thus the potential value to future readers here seems pretty low, IMO.

Comment: One other piece of information: Dot matrix printing typically uses the pritnter's built-in fonts, so the preview may be showing a Windows font but the dot matrix printer doesn't contain that exact same font. (Not sure if that's what's happening, but it's an old issue I've seen before.) Check your printer manual to see what **specific** fonts it supports internally, and then change your report's font to match and design using that font.

Comment: Thank you Mr Ken White for your help. After i read your post on meta, i agree to post the same question to FastReport Forum. But no one respond until now. Thats why i prefer asking here in stack-families than in FastReport Forum. The chance to get more respond and correct answer is high here. All right then, I will try to read Epson LQ-2180 manuals, maybe there are something useful for developers especially me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, Mr. Ken White answer is right, i have to used Escape command to the printer.

My Printer is Epson LQ-2180, so i used Epson Escape Command to set the font to be appear larger.

Here's my solution:

```
ESC ! n --> where n =  8 (Emphasized)
In Decimal would be #26#33#8
```

Thank you for the help.